# Make help-file not TopMost

Tags: c#, process, topmost

I created process and launched help-file

```
Process help = new Process();
help.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\MyProjects\comp\help_eng.hlp";
help.Start();
```

However, this help file is displaying topform;I need to open a folder for example, but it is always under this process.Could you tell me, how to make process "ordinary"? - it shouldn't be topmost!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it should not be on-top, open the .hlp file and see if its "always on top" is set under the options menu (this is a per-file setting).

Its off by default, however the .hlp could have been compiled to enable it.

(Also .hlp files wont open on vista/win7 unless the user has downloaded winhlp32)